# suid flag for su binary in Android

Tags: android, su, suid

Which script of the android build tree is giving the "suid" flag to the su binary before the system.img file is packed?
I've "grepped" for "chmod +s" or "chmod 4" strings but no luck for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution.
The file I was searching for is :

system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h

Suid binaries are defined in the "android_files" structure.
For the su binary there is this entry:

{ 06755, AID_ROOT,      AID_ROOT,      "system/xbin/su" },